# Mirror Symmetry for Flag Supermanifolds

Tags: mirror-symmetry, flag-varieties, supermanifolds, lie-superalgebras

I recently learned the following two things, and I wish to know how to make them reconciled.

(1) As far as I understand, the flag manifolds serve as a tractable class of examples for the very difficult area of mirror symmetry.

(2) There exists a generalization of the definition of flag manifolds to flag supermanifolds for Lie supergroups.

Question: Does mirror symmetry for the flag manifolds extend to the super setting.

Comment: Good question. Is there any examples of mirror for any supermanifold ? nor particulary flag ?

Comment: @Alexander https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.atmp/1143663671